# Socket.io client not receiving the emitted event from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a web app using socket.io (v4x). In the server I have a namespace to handle notifications functionality, which deals with sending notifications in different rooms whenever something happens. I am using React in frontend and Node in backend.

Server side:

```
const io = new Server(server,{
    pingTimeout:60000,
    cors:{
        origin:'http://localhost:3000',
        methods:['GET','POST','PUT','OPTIONS']
    }
});
const notificationIO = io.of('/notifications');
const chatIO = io.of('/chats');

notificationIO.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log('connected to socket.io notification feature,../')
    socket.on('join room',(courseID)=>{
        console.log(courseID,'???>>>>>')
        socket.join(courseID);
        notificationIO.to(courseID).emit('connected','..../////');
        
    })
    socket.on('new resource',(courseID)=>{
       
        console.log('notified','....////',courseID);
        notificationIO.to(courseID).emit('assignment posted','A new assignment has been posted');
    })
});
```

Client side(being used in React Context):

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export function useSocket(){
    return useContext(SocketContext)
}
export function useProvideSocket(){
   
    let socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    let [msg,setMsg] = useState("");
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        
        socket.on('assignment posted',async(message)=>{
            setMsg(message);
        })
        socket.on('connected',(message)=>{
            console.log('server sent',message);
        })
        socket.on('test',(msg)=>{
            console.log(msg,'::::::')
        })
    },[socket])
   
    function joinRoom(courseId){
        socket.emit('join room',courseId);
    }

    function newResource(courseId){
        socket.emit('new resource',courseId);
    }
    return ({
        msg,
        joinRoom,
        newResource,
        setMsg
    })
}
```

I see that a connection gets established. Problem is that I don't why I see on console logs of my server that client enters the rooms. Also the event "new resource" is also received by server but somehow the corresponding handler at client is never executed. The setMsg() is never called and so when my components want to use msg, they just have an empty string

I have tried checking the connections in network tab of dev tools. They are fine. The console logs at server-side code show that a client is connected. It is however not making sense as to why the assignment posted event fired from server is not reaching the client